# Proving the validity of an argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$$p\rightarrow q$$
$$\neg p$$
$$\overline{\therefore \neg q}$$

We were given a task to prove the validity of this argument (assuming the statement above is the same as: $(p \rightarrow q) \wedge \neg p \Rightarrow \neg q$).

I concluded with the argument to be valid. If $q$ is $0$, then the conclusion is $1$. For $p \rightarrow q$ to be true, then $p$ has to be $0$. Then $\neg p$ is $1$. This makes LHS and RHS to be $1$. Did I understand this correctly, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I was not aware that you had asked this exact question before. Next time please clarify on the original question. However, I can see that the answer you got on your duplicate question didn't actually address your error in reasoning, so I'm glad I could clear it up. Feel free to ask below my answer (not a new question) if you need to clarify further.

Comment: The answer of the previous questions was however mis-approved. He/she used another statement (switching out $\neg p$ with $q$), which is my reason to re-post the question. Glad I did so, you made it quite clear to me the idea of proving an argument. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The previous answer ended with : "For example, take $q=1,p=0$" and this is enough to prove invalidity. Thus, you haven't read it, (mis-)approved it and re-asked...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I agree with you that the previous answer is enough to show invalidity, but I think more should have been said about why the reasoning was wrong, hence I believe my answer complements it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaken. The argument is only correct if **every** possible assignment of truth values that satisfies the premises **also** satisfies the conclusion. You **cannot** work backwards from the truth of the conclusion (you haven't proven it!) to determine what should or should not be true.

In your specific case, there are 3 ways that $(p \to q)$ can be true, and in 2 of them $\neg p$ is also true, and 1 of those does **not** satisfy $\neg q$, so there is 1 **counter-example scenario** to the argument. Hence it is invalid.